# DRF- Got assertion error when I give Post Request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Error

```
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `hrm_apps.configuration.serializers.CurrencySerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.
```

models.py,

```
class CurrencyMaster(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_master = models.OneToOneField(CurrencyMaster, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    conversion_rate = models.FloatField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_master.name
```

views.py,

```
class CurrencyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Currency.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CurrencySerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

serializers.py,

```
class CurrencySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    currency_master = serializers.CharField(source="currency_master.name")

    class Meta:
        model = Currency
        fields = ['id', 'currency_master', 'conversion_rate']
```

When i give post request i got assertion error like above,

```
class CurrencySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    currency_master = serializers.CharField(source="currency_master.name")

    class Meta:
        model = Currency
        fields = ['id', 'currency_master', 'conversion_rate']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Currency.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.currency_master = validated_data.get('currency_master', instance.currency_master)
        instance.conversion_rate = validated_data.get('conversion_rate', instance.conversion_rate)
        return instance
```

I tried above i got this error "ValueError: Cannot assign "{'name': 'ALL - Albania Lek'}": "Currency.currency_master" must be a "CurrencyMaster" instance". How to resolve this???

Comment: As indicated by error, the `.create()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields which in your case is `currency_master.name`. Can you let me know what are you trying to achieve? I suppose, you can easily provide the `currency_master` id while doing POST request, why do you need source field?

Comment: I want to post the data into currencymodel. my post request gives error. How can i handle One to one field??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize the `create` method.

```
class CurrencySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    currency_master = serializers.CharField(source="currency_master.name")

    class Meta:
        model = Currency
        fields = ['id', 'currency_master', 'conversion_rate']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        currency_master_name = validated_data.pop('currency_master')["name"]
        currency_master_obj = get_object_or_404(CurrencyMaster, name=currency_master_name)
        validated_data["currency_master"] = currency_master_obj
        return Currency.objects.create(**validated_data)
```